# Dynamically update time without refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, html

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function updateClock() {
    var time = now.getHours() + ':' + now.getMinutes(), 
    document.getElementById('current').innerHTML = time;
    setTimeout(updateClock, 1000);
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="updateClock()">
<p id="current"> </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Above is the code for dynamically update real time, it is not showing any thing on the browser. Would really appreciate help

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Show time using Js :

```js
function startTime() {
  var today = new Date();
  var h = today.getHours();
  var m = today.getMinutes();
  var s = today.getSeconds();
  m = checkTime(m);
  s = checkTime(s);
  document.getElementById('current').innerHTML =
    h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
  var t = setTimeout(startTime, 500);
}

function checkTime(i) {
  if (i < 10) {
    i = "0" + i
  }; // add zero in front of numbers < 10
  return i;
}
```

```html
<body onload="startTime()">
  <p id="current">Time loading..</p>
</body>
```

OR

Your code edited:

```js
function updateClock() {
  var now = new Date();
  var time = now.getHours() + ':' + now.getMinutes() + ':' + now.getSeconds();
  document.getElementById('current').innerHTML = time;
  setTimeout(updateClock, 1000);
}
```

```html
<body onload="updateClock()">
  <p id="current"></p>
</body>
```

You were missing `var now = new Date();` and also `now.getSeconds();`.

Comment: @mplungjan my actual answer was the first one. Later realized maybe the OP wanted his code edited so posted that.

Comment: I just wondered what your answer(s) added to the issues at hand... I could not see anything not handled by the answers already posted.

Answer (score 0):

There are some errors in updateClock:

```
function updateClock() {
  var now = new Date()
  var time = now.getHours() + ':' + now.getMinutes();
  document.getElementById('current').innerHTML = time;
  setTimeout(updateClock, 1000);
}
```

`now` must be a Date object.

Comment: Also using window.onload and setInterval would be improvements

Comment: Thank you for the reply. @ema I added var now statement, it is still not showing any output

Answer (score 0):

1. `now` needed to be a date object
2. You had a comma instead of a semicolon after now.getMinutes(),

I recommend using
* padding
* setInterval
* `window.onload` instead of `body onload`

I added seconds to show it updates. If you only need hours and minutes, change the interval time to 10000 or so.

```js
function pad(num) {
  return String("0"+num).slice(-2);
}
function updateClock() {
  var now = new Date();
  var time = pad(now.getHours()) + ':' + pad(now.getMinutes()) + ":" + pad(now.getSeconds());
  document.getElementById('current').innerHTML = time;
}
window.onload = function() {
  setInterval(updateClock, 500); // use a shorter interval for better update
}
```

```html
<p id="current"></p>
```